What does it mean for the eye to grow old because of enemies?
Psalm 6:7 (NASB)

7 My eye has wasted away with grief; It has grown old because of all
my enemies.

What does it mean for the eye to grow old because of enemies?
It's clearly a metaphor. Perhaps the question should be why is David's eye growing old because of his enemies? Where is the connection between an old eye and enemies?

I have personally seen this effect reported by David in Ps 6:7 - great, extended worry and anxiety can and does cause more rapid aging.
[Side story: Relatives of my spouse were caught in a great storm that resulted in a flood.  They climbed into the roof space of their house just before it was lifted from its foundations and moved a great distance by the flood.  They survived, but when rescued, they had turned grey in less than 24 hours and could barely speak.  The horrifying experience had aged them perhaps 15 or 20 years.]
The point is, the mental stress of an extended and extreme life-threatening situation(s) has deleterious effects on the human body - a simply matter of general observation.
David reports the same thing - his life as a soldier, in countless life-threatening circumstances had taken a toll on his body by causing it to age faster, in this case, by declining eyesight.

+1. Very relevant. I was trying to study every verse carefully. This makes good sense.

Psalm 6 is the first confessional poem, with others including Psalm 32, 38, 51, 102, 130 and 143. In these poems, what causes the poet pain is his own sin, and thus the mourning within them is a form of confession.
Psalm 6:6 is significant due to its connection with Psalm 6:7:

I am worn out from my groaning. All night long I flood my bed with weeping
and drench my couch with tears. (NIV)

The poet, David, describes himself as flooding his bed with tears all night long. This sorrow arises from his own sin, causing his soul great distress for having displeased his Lord. His mental state is depicted in Psalm 6:1-3

1 Lord, do not rebuke me in your anger
or discipline me in your wrath.
2 Have mercy on me, Lord, for I am faint;
heal me, Lord, for my bones are in agony.
3 My soul is in deep anguish.
How long, Lord, how long? (NIV)

Psalm 6:7 can be interpreted literally and spiritually.
Literal Interpretation
David's eyes shed so much tears that they becomes dull, heavy and sunken, like those of an old man (Pulpit Commentary). The term "enemy" can be understood literally as "those who distress me" (Cambridge Bible for Schools and Colleges). These are not wartime enemies but rather adversaries around David who take pleasure in his suffering. David saw their actions as a reminder from God of his own sin. An example of this is found in 2 Samuel 16:5-13, where Shimei curses David.
Spiritual Interpretation
The dullness of his eyes represents a sinful state. In Luke 11:34, Jesus says:

Your eye is the lamp of your body. When your eyes are healthy, your whole body also is full of light. But when they are unhealthy, your body also is full of darkness.


There's another question in that. 8 Depart from me, all you workers of evil,
for the Lord has heard the sound of my weeping.
9 The Lord has heard my plea;
the Lord accepts my prayer.
10 All my enemies shall be ashamed and greatly troubled;
they shall turn back and be put to shame in a moment. It seems like David is speaking about a literal enemy.

I apologize for any confusion. The term "enemy" refers not to wartime enemy, but to those adversaries surrounding David who take pleasure in his suffering. David saw their actions as a reminder from God of his own sins. An example of this is found in 2 Samuel 16:5-13, where Shimei curses David. I will have my answer edited.
